# How can I convert a string to an int array in C#?

Tags: c#

for example suppose that I have a string like "231143" and I wanna convert it to an int[] array which I can easily access 2,3,1,1,4,3 as an int. What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Without any error checking you can do:

```
var value = "231143";
var array = value.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray();
```

This makes use of a trick whereby you can subtract `'0'` from the value of a single character holding a number to get its integer value.

Comment: Note that this solution is only correct if it is guranteed that the input string **only** contains digits

Comment: @Ackdari I think we can safely assume this given by the wording of the question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. thank you